# Inspect doesn't Return Data Type of a Function

Tags: python-3.x, faker

I am trying to use [joke2k/faker](https://github.com/joke2k/faker) to generate fake data. To allow dynamic generation using function name, e.g. `"random_int"`, I use
[inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) to find signature of the function. The signuare should include data type and default value of input parameters.

```py
inspect.signature(fake.random_int)
```

But it returns following without data type:

```
<Signature (min=0, max=9999, step=1)>
```

I examine [source code of the function](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/providers/__init__.py#L310) in faker library, which `inspect` should return `<Signature (min: int = 0, max: int = 9999, step: int = 1) -> int>`.

```
def random_int(self, min: int = 0, max: int = 9999, step: int = 1) -> int:
    """Generate a random integer between two integers ``min`` and ``max`` inclusive
    while observing the provided ``step`` value.
    This method is functionally equivalent to randomly sampling an integer
    from the sequence ``range(min, max + 1, step)``.
    :sample:
    :sample size=10: min=0, max=15
    :sample size=10: min=0, max=15, step=3
    """
    return self.generator.random.randrange(min, max + 1, step)
```

Could python typing be lost when code is compiled into python library? How can I re-compile the library which preserve the typing?

Answer (score 0):

Above scenario happens for Faker == 8.16.0.
After upgrade Faker to version 9.8, `inspect.signature()` returns correct typing.